# Constant stepped values in a new array

Tags: java, arrays, increment

I would like to create a new array, based on minimum and maximum values in constant intervals. For example, suppose my `min = 5` and `max = 50` and `steps = 5`, how can I create a new array that starts at `min` and goes to `max` increments of `steps`?

So that my array can look like this : `[5, 10, 15, 20...., 50]`

I tried the following but it does not seem to work:

```
int myArr[] = {};

myArr[0] = min;

for(int i = min, i <= max; i++){
   myArr[i] = min + step;
}
```

Any help or advice will be highly appreciated.

Comment: 1. Obviously it won't work, won't even compile - it isn't a correct syntax for a `for` loop. 2. Arrays have constant size, you need to calculate amount of elements beforehand and initialize it with correct size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify the size of the array. You should do as follows:

```
public class SOTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int min = 5; // use whatever you prefer
        int max = 50; // use whatever you prefer
        int step = 5; // use whatever you prefer

        // now, determine size
        // its a simple calculation, that
        // determines how many elements would there be from min to
        // max if we jump by step
        int size = (max + step - min) / step;

        int[] myArr = new int[size]; // while creating array you need to specify
        // the size of the array, i.e. how many elements the array could hold

        int val = min;
        for(int i = 0; i <size; i++){
           myArr[i] = val;
           val = val + step;
        }

        for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
           System.out.print(myArr[i] + " ");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

And the output is:

```
5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50
```

[P.S.]: If anything is unclear, just ask me in the comment section...

Comment: Aah that makes sense. My bad, thank you so much. Thank you for your time and help and explanations, much appreciated.